# combobox data bind (C# winforms)

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, data-binding, combobox

where is the problem with this code? When i start the program there is no values to choose from comboBox. There is no problems with compiling and starting an application. I have no idea what is wrong here. Maybe someone have solution for this problem.

Link to pastebin https://pastebin.com/pASVNWq

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace parKing_new
{
    public partial class editClient : Form
    {
        public editClient()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {}

    //Load customer ID to a combobox
        private void LoadCustomersId()
        {
            var connectionString = 
"Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=ewisys;Uid=root;password=;";
            using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var query = "SELECT clientID FROM clients";
                using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        //Iterate through the rows and add it to the 
combobox's items
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString("clientID"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
       }

        //Load customer details using the ID
        private void LoadCustomerDetailsById(int id)
        {
            var connectionString = 
"Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=ewisys;Uid=root;password=;";
            using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
           {
               connection.Open();
               var query = "SELECT clientID, name, surName FROM clients WHERE 
Id = @clientID";
                using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                //Always use SQL parameters to avoid SQL injection and it 
automatically escapes characters
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientID", id);
                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        //No customer found by supplied ID
                        if (!reader.HasRows)
                            return;

                        ClientIDTextBox.Text = 
                    reader.GetInt32("clientID").ToString();
                    nameTextBox.Text = reader.GetString("name");
                    surNameTextBox.Text = reader.GetString("surName");
                    }
                }
           }
       }

      private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var clientID = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text);
            LoadCustomerDetailsById(clientID);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue

Comment: Are you calling `LoadCustomersId` at some point? You should add `Load` event and call `LoadCustomersId` on that event!

Comment: please show your effort when you debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code.

The reason behind this is that when you launch your application, nothing is calling LoadCustomersId() function to populate the data on your comboBox. So use the Load event handler and populate your combobox from there:

```
private void editClient_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       LoadCustomersId();
    }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, now I can see IDs in comboBox, but I can't see values I textboxes when I click any index. Can you help me with this too? My goal is to get Client from comboBox and next step will be the button to delete a record from a database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have only defined  LoadCustomersId() method, but you are not calling it from anywhere.you need to call the method